# Saving resource on shared framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-frameworks

I'm making a framework for iOS that collect data from the phone (GPS, WiFi, etc) and sends to a server and notifies the user on events.

My problem is that if two or more apps use the framework on the same device it will consume the battery and I only need to send the data from one app because the collection continues in the background.

Is there any way to know if these multiple apps are running and notify the app that other app is collection and sending the data?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The apps are sandboxed and cannot interact.

The framework will have no way of communicating with the other apps unless it sets-up some sort of networking on the client (not advised).

I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

I'll probably look the problem inside out. When I start receiving info on the server from same ip/mac combination simultaneously I'll return a flag to all but one client on that particular device. When my framework receive that kind of flag, it will stop sending data, because someone else is already doing the same.

PS Your framework sounds like creepy spy thing though :)

Comment: Except that you can't access the Mac address on the device or from a remote server and the IP address alone is meaningless due to NAT

Comment: It's not spy thing it's just give the users location based data

Comment: Ok, my bad. How about sending IDFA from the framework. Although this comes with other responsabilities(Apple may reject app that do not contain ads).

Comment: Why downvote - IDFA will be the same across apps on one device. I'm eager to make discussion on this topic as I think this is completely doable with some restrictions.